# Approximation to unsolvable system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I am working on a project and need to find the "*closest*" numerical values that satisfy the following equations:

\begin{equation}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{}
      A \cdot C = \frac{1}{2} \\
      A \cdot D = \frac{5}{6} \\
      B \cdot C = \frac{1}{8} \\
      B \cdot D = \frac{1}{2}
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}

Where $A$ and $B$ are under the constraint that they are non-negative integers and that $C$ and $D$ must be greater than zero but less than or equal to $1$.

From what I have tried so far, it seems no analytical solution exists. For my purposes an approximate solution will suffice (matches the left-hand side of the equation to several decimal points). Having obtained my BS in engineering, my guilty pleasure is Excel's Solver add-in. Using this tool to the best of my ability, I have yet to obtain a satisfactory  approximate solution.

I am not asking anyone to "*solve*" this for me (though I wouldn't object), but would appreciate being pointed in the right direction. To summarize:

- I need to find values for $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ which fall under the
  constraints mentioned above and provide the closest values to the
  actual values on the left-hand side of the above equations.
- If the closest values are still unsatisfactory, is there someway of
  proving that they are indeed the "*best*" set of values (assuming the
  method used to find them does not inherently identify the "*best*"
  set).
- If there is a matter of tradeoff in accuracy vs integer size, I would
  prefer the smallest value integers possible that still provide
  reasonably close solutions to the equations (several decimal points).

Comment: You've got a problem: what is $A\times B\times C\times D$? You get one value if you calculate it by multiplying $(A\times C)\times(B\times D)$, but another value if you get it from $(A\times D)\times(B\times C)$. So the equations are inconsistent. How should that be handled?

Comment: To be fair, if the title says that this is an unsolvable system of equations, how are we to even approximate it if we know it can't have a solution?

Comment: @SimpleArt If some set of parameters exist that provide values 99.99% similar to the 'exact' solutions, those parameters would be satisfactory. In other words, having a set of parameters return A*C as 0.50001 (and similarly for the other equations), this would be fine.

Comment: @DavidZ If it matters at all, A * B * C * D is meaningless in the sense that this value will not be used by me for anything. If this has greater implications on finding a set of approximate parameters, then I have no idea how it should be handled.

Comment: @BattleWalrus Yes, but there is no solution for $A,B,C,D$ that will even satisfy such parameters.

Comment: @BattleWalrus I will warn you that many users on this Q/A site take math very seriously, and to simply say that something found directly from the given information is "meaningless" when others users come to the same conclusion may put you on bad sides.  Just a fair warning.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thanks for the warning. Was trying to mitigate the use of the word 'meaningless' by saying 'to me' but if it makes it any better I can edit that to "has no physical meaning relevant to my purposes"

Comment: @BattleWalrus Whether or not it has physical meaning to you does not impact its significance when trying to solve your problem.  I think one must be open minded and try to accept all one sees on this site, and you will learn much, BS in engineering or not.  ;)

Comment: @SimpleArt Again, I realize that there is no solution. I am interested in an approximate solution. If this isn't making sense, imagine two parabolas whose vertexes(vertices?) are almost intersecting, but not quite. Even though there is no 'solution' I would still very much want to use the values resulting in the closest point of intersection.

Comment: @BattleWalrus Well, I can't take you to make a 4 dimensional graph of the system and take approximations from there, can I?  My thoughts say that a somewhat close answer would be {$A,B,C,D$}$=${$1,1,1,1$}, from imagining what the graph of such a problem would look like.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you probably should replace your equations by inequalities, for example: $$|A \cdot C-\frac{1}{2}|<\alpha \\ |A \cdot D-\frac{5}{6}|<\beta$$ and so on. Then you work on minimization of all these parameters. So it actually turns into a very complicated optimization problem

Comment: Let A,B,C,D be any four numbers, AD etc. be products of pairs, and ad etc. be the prescribed values for those products (e.g., ac=1/2). Then we have (ad.bc)/(ac.bd) = (5/48)/(1/4) = 5/12 but (AD.BC)/(AC.BD) = 1; therefore the product (AD/ad) (BC/bc) (ac/AC) (bd/BD) = 12/5; therefore at least one of those four factors must be at least the fourth root of 12/5, or about 1.24. So there's no hope of getting the values as close as 0.50001 instead of 0.5; some of them must be quite far wrong.

Comment: It therefore probably matters quite a lot exactly how the errors matter to you. E.g., one of the answers below tries to minimize the sum (AC-1/2)^2 + etc.; another tries to minimize the sum (log(AC)-log(1/2))^2 + etc. The "best" solution will depend on what "best" means, which will depend on what these numbers are for and what significance your equations actually have.

Comment: Here's a (non-)solution almost exactly opposite in spirit to the ones in the existing answers. Pick three of your four equations; we'll make them hold exactly. E.g., let's take the first three. Then we can pick any A and successively take C=(1/2)/A, D = (5/6)/A, B = (1/8)/C = A/4. This gives BD=5/24 rather than the desired 1/2; note that the error here doesn't depend on our choice of A. You wanted A,B to be integers, so take A to be an integer multiple of 4 and that'll work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let

$$x_1 := \log_2 (a) \qquad \qquad x_2 := \log_2 (b) \qquad \qquad x_3 := \log_2 (c) \qquad \qquad x_4 := \log_2 (d)$$

Thus, the original system of bilinear equations can be transformed into a system of linear equations

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\\ x_4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1\\ \log_2 \left(\frac 5 6\right)\\ -3\\ -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Find the **least-squares** solution $(\hat x_1, \hat x_2, \hat x_3, \hat x_4)$ and then compute the corresponding $(\hat a,\hat b,\hat c,\hat d)$.

---

In MATLAB:

```
>> A = [1 0 1 0; 1 0 0 1; 0 1 1 0; 0 1 0 1]

A =

     1     0     1     0
     1     0     0     1
     0     1     1     0
     0     1     0     1

>> b = [-1; log2(5/6); -3; -1]

b =

   -1.0000
   -0.2630
   -3.0000
   -1.0000
```

Unfortunately, the matrix is singular:

```
>> det(A)

ans =

     0
```

We then find **one** solution to the "normal equations":

```
>> x = (A' * A)\(A' * b)

x =

    1.7194
    0.3509
   -3.0351
   -1.6667
```

The corresponding $(\hat a,\hat b,\hat c,\hat d)$ is, thus:

```
>> y = 2.^x

y =

    3.2930
    1.2754
    0.1220
    0.3150
```

We introduce a new matrix:

```
>> Y = y * y'

Y =

   10.8437    4.1997    0.4017    1.0372
    4.1997    1.6266    0.1556    0.4017
    0.4017    0.1556    0.0149    0.0384
    1.0372    0.4017    0.0384    0.0992
```

The absolute error is:

```
>> Y(1:2,3:4) - [1/2,5/6;1/8,1/2]

ans =

   -0.0983    0.2039
    0.0306   -0.0983
```

which is quite large.

Comment: +1: Didn't realize that I was suggesting a similar approach :D.

Comment: @MrYouMath Your approach is *nonlinear* least-squares, though.

Comment: @MrYouMath and Rodrigo, both your approaches are useful: an NLLS method usually needs a good starting point, so one can use Rodrigo's method as a starting guess, and then MrYouMath's method can then be used for polishing. Also, since we're talking about stuff like this: this optimizes with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$; one might also consider solutions that optimize with respect to e.g. the Manhattan or Chebyshev norms.

Comment: @J.M. Very nice addition with the other norms :).

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:** If you stuff the variables into vectors, your problem becomes:

$$M = \left[\begin{array}{c}A\\B\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}C&D\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{rr} \frac{1}{2} & \frac 56\\\frac 1 8&\frac 1 2 \end{array}\right]$$

This means we want to find the best rank 1 match to the matrix.

---

**Thanks** for @Ian s comment which clarified nicely that you can use for example the [Singular Value Decomposition ( SVD )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) to find the best match.

The SVD says $M = U\Sigma V^*$ where the values in the diagonal $\Sigma$ are the singular values. If we pick the column in U and the row in $V^*$ which correspond to the largest singular value, we can identify the $A,B,C$ and $D$ above.

---

Some Matlab/Octave code to do the SVD approximation:

```
  M = [1/2,5/6;1/8,1/2];
  [U,S,V]=svd(M);
  U(:,1)*S(1,1)*V(:,1)'   % rank 1 SVD appr. as index 1 contains largest s.v.
```

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0.445505865263938&0.861513345600555\\
0.230380036476643&0.445505865263938
\end{array}\right]$$

```
abs(M-U(:,1)*S(1,1)*V(:,1)')  %and the absolute error
```

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0.0544941347360618&0.028180012267222\\
0.105380036476643&0.0544941347360618
\end{array}\right]$$

We can see the error distributed so that each element has a rather different error. It differs $10.5/2.8 \approx 3.74$ times smallest compared to largest. As mentioned in comments, if we are not OK with this distribution of the error, we may want to try minimize the error according to some other norm.

Comment: I fail to see the significance of this hint...?

Comment: It becomes a problem of finding the closest rank-1 match which is a very well studied problem in linear algebra.

Comment: What is the `closest rank-1 match`?

Comment: @FrenzyLi You have the outer product of two vectors $u v^T$. This is a rank 1 matrix ($uv^Tx$ is always a multiple of $u$). You can identify the rank 1 matrix which is closest to $\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 5/6 \\ 1/8 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$ using the SVD, and then solve the *consistent* problem where you put that rank 1 matrix on the right side instead.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. (Would you move the comments into the answer?)

Comment: Yes great comment Ian, thank you.

Comment: @FrenzyLi It's not my answer :) I'll leave it up to mathreadler.

Comment: Some Matlab code: A=[1/2 5/6;1/8 1/2];[U,S,V]=svd(A);Sc=[S(1,1) 0;0 0];Ac=U\*Sc\*V';fsolve(@(x) [x(1)\*x(3)-Ac(1,1);x(1)\*x(4)-Ac(1,2);x(2)\*x(3)-Ac(2,1);x(2)*x(4)-Ac(2,2)],[1;1;1;1]). From this I get $A \approx 0.81,B \approx 0.42,C \approx 0.55,D \approx 1.1$ (just retaining two digits each, Matlab gives more of course). So it looks like this does work even in practice. Good approach.

Comment: The only thing you might think is bad about this approach is that the $2 \times 2$ matrix 2-norm is quite different from a more familiar norm like the $4 \times 1$ vector 2-norm. Still, you could use this as an initial guess for a method for optimizing in some other norm.

Answer (score 7):

Another way you could try to approach this problem by using a least squares estimator.

Assume $$F(A,B,C,D)=(AC-1/2)^2+(AD-5/6)^2+(BC-1/5)^2+(BD-1/2)^2$$

Now calculate the gradient of $F$
$$\nabla F=\left[\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial A},\cdots,\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial D}\right]$$

Then set the gradient to zero. Solve the resulting nonlinear system using Newton-Raphson algorithm (you should also check the positiveness of the Hessian).

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers thus far have dealt with the integer constraint on $(A,B)$.
If we define two vectors, one integer and one real,
$$\eqalign{
a &= [\, A \,\, B \,]^T \cr
x &= [\, C \,\, D \,]^T \cr
}$$
Then the problem is to minimize the function $$f=\|M-ax^T\|^2_F$$
where $M = [\, 1/2 \,\,\, 5/6;\, 1/8 \,\,\,1/2 \,]$.

Assume that the integer vector, $a$, is known or given. Then by setting the gradient zero, we can solve explicitly for the optimum real vector
$$\eqalign{ x &= \frac{M^Ta}{a^Ta} }$$
Now all we need to do is write a program to search through lots of integer vectors.

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env  julia
> M = [ 1/2 5/6; 1/8 1/2 ];
> n=999; fmin=5.0;
> for i=1:n, j=1:n
>    a = [i j]';
>    x = M'*a/(a'*a);
>    f = vecnorm(M-a*x');
>    if f < fmin
>       @printf("(%d,%d), ", i,j)
>       fmin = f
>    end
> end
> (1,1), (2,1), (15,8), (17,9), (19,10), (21,11), (23,12), (25,13),
> (27,14), (29,15), (147,76), (176,91), (205,106), (234,121),
> (263,136), (292,151), (555,287), (847,438)
> ```

Note that the ratio  (i/j) is approximately $1.9$ for all these solutions.  To speed things up, we can use this ratio to limit the range on the second index, and extend the search range to even larger integers.

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env  julia
> M = [ 1/2 5/6; 1/8 1/2 ];
> i,j = (847,438);
> a=[i j]'; x=M'*a/(a'*a);
> n=99999; fmin=vecnorm(M-a*x');
> for i=1:n, j=round(Int,i/2.1):round(Int,i/1.7)
>    a = [i j]'
>    x = M'*a/(a'*a)
>    f = vecnorm(x*a'-M')
>    if f < fmin
>       @printf("(%d,%d), ", i,j)
>       fmin = f
>    end
> end
> (1139,589), (3125,1616), (4264,2205),
> (5403,2794), (9667,4999), (52599,27200)
> ```

The solution corresponding to the penultimate index pair is
$$\eqalign{
  a &= [\, 9667 \,\,\, 4999 \,]^T \cr
  x &= [\, 4.6085224452467385 \,\,\, 8.91189971076149 \,]^T \times 10^{-5} \cr
  f &= 0.017838286620463398 \cr
}$$
The best of the small ($\le 100$) index pairs is 
$$\eqalign{
  a &= [\, 29 \,\,\, 15 \,]^T \cr
  x &= [\, 0.015361163227016885 \,\,\, 0.029706066291432145 \,]^T \cr
  f &= 0.01783829737335834 \cr
}$$

Answer (score 1):

The OP's last bullet point led me to a different attack on this problem.

First, note that if $(a,b,c,d)$ is a suitable approximate solution, then so is $(k a, k b, c/k, d/k)$ for any positive integer $k$.  The last bullet prefers smaller integers, so we will want $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b) = 1$.

Suppose we relax the equalities to memberships in intervals of a given radius:  \begin{align}
    a c &\in [1/2 - \varepsilon, 1/2 + \varepsilon] = 1/2 + \varepsilon[-1,1]\\
    a d &\in [5/6 - \varepsilon, 5/6 + \varepsilon] = 5/6 + \varepsilon[-1,1]\\
    b c &\in [1/8 - \varepsilon, 1/8 + \varepsilon] = 1/8 + \varepsilon[-1,1]\\
    b d &\in [1/2 - \varepsilon, 1/2 + \varepsilon] = 1/2 + \varepsilon[-1,1] \text{,}
\end{align} where the first equality uses usual interval notation and the second form uses usual interval arithmetic notation.

Then we can control the number of digits of agreement by setting $\varepsilon$ to suitable negative powers of $10$.

This suggests a process:

- Pick a $(c,d) \in (0,1] \times (0,1]$.
- Find the smallest $\varepsilon$ so that there is still an integer point, $(a,b)$, satisfying the four membership relations.
- Find the largest region on the $c$-$d$ plane where this $(a,b)$ has minimal epsilon of all integer points.

This allows us to partition the square $(0,1] \times (0,1]$ into regions where a particular integer point is optimal and search for the point in that region with minimal $\varepsilon$.  In fact, once $a$ and $b$ are fixed, this is a search with linear constraints, so is pretty easy.

By computer algebra system (Mathematica 10.4.1), for $(c,d) = (1/6,1/2)$, the minimum $\varepsilon$ still admitting an integer point satisfying the membership relations is $\varepsilon = 1/6$ for $(a,b) = (2,1)$.  For this $(a,b)$, the largest region in the $c$-$d$ plane where each point has minimal $\varepsilon$ at this integer point is $(c,d) \in [1/5,1/4]\times[1/3,5/9]$.  In that region, the minimum value of $\varepsilon$ is $1/12$, attained at $(c,d) = (5/24, 5/12)$.  This is not so impressive (since $\varepsilon = 1/12$ means that we only have a trifle more than  one decimal agreement with the original equalities).  (There is another minimum in this region, at $(c,d) = (5/24,7/16)$ yielding the same extreme value of $\varepsilon = 1/12$.  However, there do not appear to be criteria for preferring points on the $c$-$d$ plane.)

(It's late/early here, so I'll continue hacking on this analytically some time in the next few days.  Note to self:  Use the $(ka, kb, c/k, d/k)$ relation to rewrite $c$ and $d$ ($\in [1,\infty)$) to give solutions $(ka, kb, kc, kd)$, then projectively set $b=1$ (or $a=1$, if there are also solutions with $b>a$).)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\\ c\\ d\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\\ c\\ d\end{bmatrix}^\top = \begin{bmatrix} a^2 & a b & a c & a d\\ a b & b^2 & b c & b d\\ a c & b c & c^2 & c d\\ a d & b d & c d & d^2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a^2 & a b & \frac 12 & \frac 56\\ a b & b^2 & \frac 18 & \frac 12\\ \frac 12 & \frac 18 & c^2 & c d\\ \frac 56 & \frac 12 & c d & d^2\end{bmatrix}$$

Let us look for a symmetric, positive semidefinite, rank-$1$ matrix $\mathrm X \in \mathbb R^{4 \times 4}$ whose northeast and southwest $2 \times 2$ blocks are equal to the northeast and southwest $2 \times 2$ blocks in the matrix above.

Hence, we have a rank-minimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mbox{rank} (\mathrm X) \\ \text{subject to} & x_{13} = \frac 12, \quad x_{14} = \frac 56\\ & x_{23} = \frac 18, \quad x_{24} = \frac 12\\ & \mathrm X = \mathrm X^\top\\ & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_4\end{array}$$

Unfortunately, minimizing the rank is computationally hard [0]. Thus, let us minimize the **nuclear norm** of $\mathrm X$ instead. Since $\mathrm X$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite, its nuclear norm is given by

$$\|\mathrm X\|_* = \mbox{tr} (\mathrm X)$$

Hence, we obtain the following **semidefinite program** (SDP)

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mbox{tr} (\mathrm X) \\ \text{subject to} & x_{13} = \frac 12, \quad x_{14} = \frac 56\\ & x_{23} = \frac 18, \quad x_{24} = \frac 12\\ & \mathrm X = \mathrm X^\top\\ & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_4\end{array}$$

Using MATLAB + [CVX](http://cvxr.com),

```
clear all; clc;

cvx_begin sdp
    variable X(4,4) symmetric
    minimize( trace(X) )
    subject to
        X(1,3)==1/2
        X(1,4)==5/6
        X(2,3)==1/8
        X(2,4)==1/2
        X >= 0
cvx_end

% rank of X
disp('rank(X) ='); disp(rank(X))

% build rank-1 matrix
[U,S,V] = svd(X);
X_tilde = U(:,1) * S(1,1) * (V(:,1)');
disp('rank-1 approximation of X ='); disp(X_tilde)

% approximation error
disp('approximation error = '); disp(X_tilde - X)

% error matrix
disp('error matrix = '); disp(X_tilde(1:2,3:4) - [1/2,5/6;1/8,1/2])
```

---

Running this MATLAB script, we obtain the following output

```
Calling sedumi: 10 variables, 4 equality constraints
------------------------------------------------------------
SeDuMi 1.21 by AdvOL, 2005-2008 and Jos F. Sturm, 1998-2003.
Alg = 2: xz-corrector, Adaptive Step-Differentiation, theta = 0.250, beta = 0.500
eqs m = 4, order n = 5, dim = 17, blocks = 2
nnz(A) = 4 + 0, nnz(ADA) = 16, nnz(L) = 10
 it :     b*y       gap    delta  rate   t/tP*  t/tD*   feas cg cg  prec
  0 :            9.09E+000 0.000
  1 :  2.28E+000 2.11E+000 0.000 0.2322 0.9000 0.9000   1.21  1  1  7.9E-001
  2 :  2.30E+000 4.47E-001 0.000 0.2117 0.9000 0.9000   1.18  1  1  1.8E-001
  3 :  2.45E+000 1.33E-002 0.000 0.0297 0.9900 0.9900   1.01  1  1  5.5E-003
  4 :  2.45E+000 3.56E-007 0.000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000   1.00  1  1  1.4E-007
  5 :  2.45E+000 5.10E-014 0.000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000   1.00  1  1  2.1E-014

iter seconds digits       c*x               b*y
  5      0.2  13.8  2.4509068616e+000  2.4509068616e+000
|Ax-b| =  4.5e-015, [Ay-c]_+ =  0.0E+000, |x|= 2.2e+000, |y|= 2.8e+000

Detailed timing (sec)
   Pre          IPM          Post
1.719E-001    2.344E-001    7.813E-002   
Max-norms: ||b||=8.333333e-001, ||c|| = 1,
Cholesky |add|=0, |skip| = 0, ||L.L|| = 1.41176.
------------------------------------------------------------
Status: Solved
Optimal value (cvx_optval): +2.45091
rank(X) =
     4

rank-1 approximation of X =
    0.8615    0.4455    0.4455    0.8615
    0.4455    0.2304    0.2304    0.4455
    0.4455    0.2304    0.2304    0.4455
    0.8615    0.4455    0.4455    0.8615

approximation error =
   -0.0282    0.0545   -0.0545    0.0282
    0.0545   -0.1054    0.1054   -0.0545
   -0.0545    0.1054   -0.1054    0.0545
    0.0282   -0.0545    0.0545   -0.0282

error matrix =
   -0.0545    0.0282
    0.1054   -0.0545
```

---

Note that the maximum error is smaller than when using least-squares.

---

[0] Emmanuel Candès, [The Effectiveness of Convex Programming in the Information and Physical Sciences](https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/241/slidescandesemmanuel.pdf) [PDF], Simons Institute Open Lecture, UC Berkeley, October 2013.