Finding a Symbolic or Approximate Symbolic Solution for an Unknown Constant in a Complicated (Potentially Transcendental) System of Equations
The following set of equations describe a physical system, where $A$, $B$, $C$, $x_0$, and $z_0$ are known constants (with $A,B,C > 0$, $z_0 < 0$, and $C \ll 1$ but non-negligible), and $\beta \in [-A, A]$ is some unknown constant whose value I wish to determine:
$$
z(x) = \frac{1}{C}\ln\left[ \frac{2(A^2-\beta^2)e^{K(t+x)}}{\beta^2B^2e^{2xk}-2ABe^{K(t+x)}+e^{2tK}} \right]
$$
$$
n(z) = n(z(x)) = A - Be^{Cz(x)}
$$
The constants $K$ and $t$ may be expressed in terms of $\beta$ as follows:
$$
K = C\frac{\sqrt{A^2-\beta^2}}{\beta}
$$
$$
t = \frac{\sqrt{A^2-\beta^2}Cx_0 - \beta C z_0 + \beta \ln\left[ A^2 - \beta^2 +ABe^{Cz_0} + \sqrt{A^2-\beta^2}\sqrt{A^2 - \beta^2 + 2ABe^{Cz_0}+B^2e^{2Cz_0}} \right]}{\sqrt{A^2-\beta^2}C}
$$

Suppose that I know also the values of $z(x_0)$, $z(x_1)$, $n(z_0)$, and $n(z_1)$. Can I determine a symbolic, analytic formula for $\beta$?
Regrettably I don't have much to share with respect to what I've tried, as everything has been a bit of a dead end. I have successfully solved this numerically/using optimization approaches (using e.g. Newton's method), but (for a variety of reasons) now desire an analytical formula. I've tried passing this to both Mathematica and SymPy, however neither have made progress after several attempts and some hours. My own attempts have fallen flat as well, perhaps due in large part to having to keep track of the complexity of the system's dependence on $\beta$ (what I really need is a bigger chalkboard). Despite this complexity I suspect that I have sufficient information and constraints so as to arrive at a solution.
I'm open to full solutions and suggested approaches (the latter would be great, in fact... I've been working on this for a while and the satisfaction of having solved it would be great).

Edit:
I've found that the difference $z_1 - z_0$ can be manipulated to obtain:
$$
e^{C(z_1-z_0)} = \frac{\beta ^2 B^2 e^{\frac{C \sqrt{(A^2-\beta^2)} \left(x_0-t\right)}{\beta }}-2 A B+e^{\frac{C \sqrt{(A^2-\beta^2)} \left(t-x_0\right)}{\beta }}}{\beta ^2 B^2 e^{\frac{C \sqrt{(A^2-\beta^2)} \left(x_1-t\right)}{\beta }}-2 A B+e^{\frac{C \sqrt{(A^2-\beta^2)} \left(t-x_1\right)}{\beta }}}
$$
Substituting in the expression for $t$, we obtain (after some simplification):
$$
e^{C(z_1-z_0)} = \frac{2 (A^2-\beta^2) \left(A^2+\sqrt{(A^2-\beta^2)} \sqrt{\left(A-\beta +B e^{C z_0}\right) \left(A+\beta +B e^{C z_0}\right)}+A B e^{C z_0}-\beta ^2\right) e^{\frac{C \sqrt{(A^2-\beta^2)} (x_0-x_1)}{\beta }-2 C z_0}}{\left(A^2+\sqrt{(A^2-\beta^2)} \sqrt{\left(A-\beta +B e^{C z_0}\right) \left(A+\beta +B e^{C z_0}\right)}+A B e^{C z_0}-\beta ^2\right)^2 \exp \left(-2 C \left(\frac{\sqrt{(A^2-\beta^2)} (x_1-x_0)}{\beta }+z_0\right)\right)-2 A B \left(A^2+\sqrt{(A^2-\beta^2)} \sqrt{\left(A-\beta +B e^{C z_0}\right) \left(A+\beta +B e^{C z_0}\right)}+A B e^{C z_0}-\beta ^2\right) \exp \left(-C \left(\frac{\sqrt{(A^2-\beta^2)} (x_1-x_0)}{\beta }+z_0\right)\right)+\beta ^2 B^2}
$$

Edit 2: An Idea
The way I solve this numerically is to find the minimum of:
$$(z(x_1) - z_1)^2$$
---using numerical optimization methods. Finding the root of this function by e.g. differentiating and setting it equal to $0$ is challenging. Observe, however, that (for instance):
$$(ln(x) - d)^2\quad\text{and}\quad((x-1) - d)^2$$
---have the same root. Applying this particular transformation hasn't gotten me very far, but perhaps there's a clever choice of some function that shares a root with $(ln(x) - d)^2$ that yields an expression whose root in $\beta$ is easier to determine.

Boiling this down to its essentials, you have a system of nonlinear equations:
$$f_1(\beta) = y_1, f_2(\beta) = y_2, \dots, f_k(\beta) = y_k,$$
where $y_1,\dots,y_k$ are given, $f_1,\dots,f_k$ are known nonlinear functions (with some closed form you can write down), and you want to solve for $\beta$.
If you search for how to solve a system of nonlinear equations, you should find many resources.  (e.g., fsolve in Matlab)  (you can also check out other questions here about this topic)
In your case, I would suggest using an optimization-based algorithm.  Define a loss function
$$\Phi(\beta) = (f_1(\beta)-y_1)^2 + \dots + (f_k(\beta)-y_k)^2.$$
Then solving the system of nonlinear equations is equivalent to finding $\beta$ that minimizes $\Phi(\beta)$.  You can use numerical optimization methods to minimize $\Phi(\beta)$.
For instance, a reasonable approach might be to pick some guess $\beta_0$ at $\beta$, then use Newton's method to iteratively improve your guess at $\beta$ (each time finding a new $\beta$ that further reduces the value of $\Phi(\beta)$), and stop after some number of iterations.  Repeat many times with many different guesses $\beta_0$ at $\beta$, i.e., run Newton's method many times with many different initial values.  There are many other options as well for how to perform the minimization.  This is just one approach.  If you use a computer algebra system (Matlab, Mathematica, etc.), you should be able to experiment with multiple optimization methods.
See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method#k_variables.2C_k_functions and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1850921/14578.

Thanks for the detailed response! I'm familiar with numerical optimization methods, and have wrote some code to solve this problem numerically. Unfortunately, however, I now for a few reasons desire an analytical, symbolic formula for (or approximation of) the parameter $\beta$.
